# Convert textbox to float regardless of culturename, currency sign?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a jquery function that should make a calculation based on a textbox value.

That textbox has a maskededit extender, by default it shows dollar sign, and the calculation works.

When I add the culturename property it shows the euro sign, but then the calculation stops working and it returns NaN

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server"
TargetControlID="TxtVatIncluded" 
Mask="9,999,999.99"
MessageValidatorTip="true" 
OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
MaskType="Number" 
InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
DisplayMoney="Left" CultureName="nl-BE"
/> 




 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#TxtVatExcluded").focusout(function () {
                debugger;
                var invoicedAmmount = $("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").text().replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
                if (invoicedAmmount > 0) {
                    var ammountWithoutVat = parseFloat($("#TxtVatExcluded").val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""));
                    var result = ((ammountWithoutVat / invoicedAmmount) * 100).toFixed(2);
                    $("#MainContent_LblPercentage").html(result + " %");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: It seems this line fails due to inclusion of Euro sign `parseFloat($("#TxtVatExcluded").val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) javascript library can handle this scenario. Once the library is initialized with the correct language code `Globalize.culture(languageCode);`, you can use the `Globalize` version of `parseFloat` which handles the different currency symbol and numeric separators.  For example,

`Globalize.parseFloat('€9,99')` returns `9.99` when using the Dutch/Belgium language code.

Answer (score 2):

The number format of `nl-BE` is not the same as `en-US`. The number `9,999,999.99` is written `9.999.999,99`. `parseFloat` expects `9999999.99` but the regular expression you use to clean up the string removes the commas when instead it should remove the dots and replace the comma by a dot.